# Positional DataSource doesn't load all data

Tags: android, android-paging

I am trying to experiment with **Positional DataSource**. I have created the following dummy source.

```
class ContactsDataSource : PositionalDataSource<Contact>() {
    override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<Contact>) {

        val c = ArrayList<Contact>()
        for (i in params.startPosition..params.loadSize) {
            c.add(Contact("$i contact"))
        }
        callback.onResult(c)

        Logger.d("loadRange: StartPos: ${params.startPosition} LoadSize: ${params.loadSize}")

    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Contact>) {
        Logger.d("Load Initial: PageSize: ${params.pageSize} LoadSize: ${params.requestedLoadSize}")
        val c = ArrayList<Contact>()
        for (i in 0 until params.requestedLoadSize) {
            c.add(Contact("$i contact"))
        }

        callback.onResult(c, 0, 1000)
    }
}

class ContactsDsFactory : DataSource.Factory<Int, Contact>() {
    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Contact> {
        return ContactsDataSource()
    }

}
```

For the first time, it calls `loadInitial` and items are loaded. When I scroll up, it loads more items by calling `loadRange`. **After load range is called for the first time, it is never called again.** Although, the items loaded are less than the total count I have passed in `loadInitial` callback. Here is how I have setup the source.

```
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder().setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setMaxSize(120)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(60)
            .setPageSize(20).build()
        val list = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Contact>(ContactsDsFactory(), config)
            .build()
        val recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val adapter = ContactsRecycler()
        recycler.adapter = adapter
        list.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
```

These are the log

```
D/PagedLab: Load Initial: PageSize: 20 LoadSize: 60
D/PagedLab: loadRange: StartPos: 60 LoadSize: 20
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong range `for (i in params.startPosition..params.loadSize)`. Worked after setting the correct range `params.startPosition + params.loadSize`.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a class `MovieListDataSource` that extends `PositionalDataSource`.
The fact is you have to use `PagedListAdapter` and this will call `loadAround(int)`. If everything works well then there will be no loading issue. Click  [here](https://github.com/anjandebnath/ArchitectureComponent/tree/RnD_chathistory) and you will get my implementation. Hope this will help you.